# 'Linker command failed with exit code 1' when using Google Analytics via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I'm trying to add Google Analytics to an iOS app written in Swift. I've followed the guide that adds the frameworks via CocoaPods and added a bridging header but I'm still getting:

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1
```

My podfile does have use_frameworks! so I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it... there is no additional information on the Analytics site from what I can see.

EDIT:
I've noticed that after viewing the full error message the following is displayed:

```
ld: '/Users/simon/Programming/VenueNow/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)' does not contain bitcode. 
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
```

And searching for that issue brings up that Google updated to support bit code but hadn't updated the cocoa pods framework at that time.

Comment: For others with similar issue, and they have pods, be sure you run `pod install` before chasing your tail too far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same issue. Fortunately you can use Google Analytics with BitCode enabled, but it's a bit confusing due to how Google had set up their CocoaPods support.

There's actually 2 CocoaPods you can use:

- 'Google/Analytics'
- 'GoogleAnalytics'

The first one is the "latest" but it's tied to the greater Google pods so it does not support Bitcode. The second one is for Analytics only and does support BitCode. However because the latter does not include extra Google pods some of the instructions on how to set it up are incorrect.

You have to use the v2 method of setting up analytics:

```
// Inside AppDelegate:

// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20

// Create tracker instance.
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("XX-XXXXXXXX-Y")
```

The rest of the Google analytics api you can use the v3 documentation (you don't need to use v2).

The 'Google/Analytics' cocoapod as of this writing still does not support BitCode. [See here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671)

Comment: `BitCode` was the keyword that helped me. thanks dude

Answer (score 12):

Go to your build settings and switch the target's settings to `ENABLE_BITCODE = YES` for now.

Comment: Thanks but that option is already set to YES. I think the conflict is that the cocoa pods version of Analytics doesn't support bit code but the latest version should. I'm currently adding that manually and will update if it works.

Comment: For me, changing this setting to `NO` was the appropriate fix.

Comment: in CMake or clion, how can we do this? @taky2

Answer (score 7):

Had this issue, but it wasn't related to the bitcode setting. I had somehow ended up with duplicate framework files in the Frameworks folder of my XCode project. I deleted all frameworks files that were red (and duplicates). This solved the "Apple Mach O, Linker Command failed with exit code 1" error.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

> you have to remove libPods.a library from Linked Frameworks and
>   Libraries section of target.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you open the **.xcworkspace** file not the project file from xCode Project menu when working with pods. That should solve the issue with linking.

Answer (score 2):

Close Xcode, rename the folder. Then make a new folder with the previous name. Run the project, stop the project. Delete the new folder, rename old folder and re-run.

My iPad Pro simulator is affected with this issue. Its something that makes me upset, so much hard work... hopefully Google works through bugs for the next SDK.

Answer (score 1):

When I changed 'iOS Deployment Target' from 'IOS 10.0' to current one (my phone's) 'iOS 10.2', the problem was gone for me.

> Building Settings>Deployment>iOS Deployment Target

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to adding Analytics via cocoa pods again and disabled bit code for now.

Hopefully a future cocoa pods version will support it.

Answer (score 0):

You have another option... install Google Analytics without using CocoaPods:

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download

Answer (score 0):

I had same the problem with xcode 7.3. It is because, some of my .h and .m files were added twice.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when using Cocoapods and you are building from the xcproject which doesn't know about the cocoapod libraries.

Comment: So do you have more information, how to link the cocoapod libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Some times appeared if you declare a constant in the header file without static notation. 
like this

```
const int k = 10;
```

it should be:

```
static const int k = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove any trace of cocoapods pods using `pod deintegrate` then
Run `pod install`

Answer (score -2):

Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > No

Comment: a little bit more text would be nice. But in fact, this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35290286/2987273 (only with fewer text)

Comment: thanks for the comment first ... its what i found always when i use to work on demo or examples downloaded from git for assistance .. same issue i faced with my new google_map app . as its working on simulator but not on device ...