# FreshChat iOS build is failing

Tags: ios, react-native

When I am running the build on XCode, its showing following error -

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

library not found for -lFDFreshchatSDK

I have tried adding Library Search path also but no solution.

Comment: What's freshchat?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-freshchat-sdk

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327427/14351818

Comment: Exact error is library not found for -lFDFreshchatSDK